# How to parse html links beginning with `./`

Tags: html, url

Is an anchor href starting with `./` supposed to be parsed as a folder with a name of `.` or as a path relative to the current root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC1808 says you should to ignore them, no matter where in the path they are.

```
All occurrences of "./", where "." is a complete path segment, are removed.

If the path ends with "." as a complete path segment, that "." is removed.
```

This means a link such as `./folder/file.txt` would become `folder/file.txt` which is a path relative to the current directory, and it should be handled as such.